# How do I prevent abuse of my api's by 3rd parties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, security

I have an endpoint that verifies that email addresses are deliverable call it https://testService.com/verify. This endpoint comes with an api key, lets call it 'AbCd' if you concatenate both of those things and an email address in a query string and perform a get request, it gives tells you if the email address is deliverable. I am using this to validate a form and only submit if the email address is deliverable. The page where this is being used is an e-commerce landing page were no login is required so  using google O-auth is not a possibility.

The problem becomes I cannot hardcode the api key "AbCd" in the front end because it is then insecure and theoretically someone could rip the api key and use the service on their own forms on our dime.

Conventional wisdom says I should execute this call on the back end and then forward the response to the app however if I make a call from the back end the front end still has to call the back end, you can find where it is making the call from the network tab and then use it in other apps.

You could secure the back end with a api key however this just brings you full circle to where we started. With an endpoint and an api key.

Comment: Well, the browser needs this information, so the browser must be able to call this API, and any random anonymous user needs to be able to do so, so you have a public API for all intents and purposes. You can't *hide* it. You can try to make it unnecessary to expose this API, e.g. by simply not making this check, accepting the email address, and silently drop it if it's "undeliverable". Then there's no useful external API to abuse. Otherwise you can only rate limit it by IP, the usual DoS/abuse detection/prevention.

Comment: Should you make the call from your back-end? Certainly, you should not leak your (potentially paid-for) API key for a 3rd party. How do you protect against misuse? That's a huge topic. You want to do something for free (checking the email). However, you don't want people to abuse this. You can either disregard the issue, until it happens, or do things like captchas, proof-of-work, etc, to introduce minimal cost, larger than verifying an email.

Comment: PS: DoS-protection is very similar - if it's not straight out UDP-flood, the problem typically stems from servers doing some minimal work in response to a packet (more than the effort to send the packet), because they assume legitimate users, and in a way "offer this minimal work for free". This goes so far, that protocol-design can involve considerations like "can't do this, the server may not do work first, the client has to be forced to work first".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to verify on server side that a request has been sent from the web page of your frontend, **you can't**. An API key is easily readable by anyone, and every HTTP header can be spoofed, so there is no reliable way to achieve that.

The best thing you could do is verify that a request comes from a real person, which can be achieved with a captcha.